# How do I use AppController without overriding it?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I need to override the AppController function while creating the unity plugin.

So I registered a subclass through the IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS macro, but I got a problem with other plug-ins crashing

```
@interface Test1 : UnityAppController
@end

@interface Test2 : UnityAppController
@end

IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS (Test1)
IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS (Test2)

@implementation Test1
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"-> Test1 :: applicationDidFinishLaunching()\n"); // <- NOT WORKING!
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end

@implementation Test2
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"-> Test2 :: applicationDidFinishLaunching()\n");
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end
```

If IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS is used more than once, only one of them will be applied, so didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in Test1 will not be called.

Is there a way to get a function call without overriding the AppController?

Comment: Create strong ref of . Test1 class  (create property )in Test2 and call it manually like`[test1Obj  application:]...`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Thank you for your feedback. But I do not want to create dependencies between Test1 and Test2.